# validation for image check in update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How to check validation for image(input type="file") in edit section. Whenever I want to update, it asks if the image is there or not. How to check properly if the image exists or not and validate it?

I wrote like this:

```
<?php if($records[0]->proof==""){ ?>
    <input type="file"  name="proof" >
<?php }else{ ?>
    <input type="file"  name="proof"  value="<?php echo $records[0]->proof; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

JS:

```
 $("form[name='frm']").validate({
  rules: {
    proof: { required: true, filesize: 4194304 }
    },
    messages:{
        proof: { required: "Please Upload  Proofs",filesize:"Please upload file size less than 4MB"}
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("form[name='frm']").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: any extension @TarangP

Comment: Yes Any of extension.

Comment: validation is working  properly but in update the form the image is not checking if there are not so it asks validation everytime

Comment: it means you want when user updates detail if image is not available only than validation works else validation can't.

Comment: You cannot set the default `value` of the `input` field due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To check if file uploaded by user in input field, you can use `$('#file-input').val()`.

HTML:

```
<input type="file"  name="proof" id="file-input">
```

JS:

```
var file = $('#file-input').val();
if(file)
{
//do something else
}
else
{
//do something else
}
```

As in your post. You are setting `default value` for `input` field which is wrong. You cannot set the `default` value of input field due to security reasons.